Data prop responsiveness issue when input bind:value in Svelt
When export let data is an object, there is a data prop reactivity problem when using input bind:value.
For example, in the following case
<script>
export let data = {name:"jack", age:31};
$: man = data;
</script>
<input type='text' bind:value={man.name} >
<h1>{data.name}</h1>
<h1>{man.name}</h1>

//input typing jhon
//data.name => jhon
//man.name => jhon

When the bare value of the input changes, the value of the data also changes at the same time.
I think it's because of shallow copying.
So, in the case below where deep copy is performed,
<script>
export let data = {name:"jack", age:31};
$: man = structuredClone(data);
</script>
<input type='text' bind:value={man.name} >
<h1>{data.name}</h1>
<h1>{man.name}</h1>

//input typing impossible

Input values ​​cannot be changed.
Ultimately, what I want is for only the value of man to change depending on the input value. (So ​​that the data value does not change)
What am I misunderstanding?
Thank you for reading my post.
<script>
let data = {name:"jack", age:31};
$: man = data;
</script>
<input type='text' bind:value={man.name} >
<h1>{data.name}</h1>
<h1>{man.name}</h1>

//input typing jhon
//data.name => jack
//man.name => jhon

In the case of let data, it does what I want, but I have to use export let data.
There is also a way to use $page.data, but more than anything, I want to understand how the above behavior occurs. I would appreciate it if someone could explain.

I do not understand what exactly you are trying to do or why. Also, man = data is just a reference (i.e. not a copy at all) and man = Object.assign({},data) is a shallow copy.

First of all, thank you for reading my post.
I know man=data is a reference.
However, I
I thought man=Object({},data) was a deep copy.
This is the first time I realized this was a shallow copy.
The behavior I want is for the value of data to not change at the same time when the value of man changes.
This is not a problem when export let data is of value type.
This only occurs when it is a reference type.

Of course, there is no problem if you use read-only $page.data with man=$page.data.
Alternatively, there is a way to use man=event.currentTarget.value in the handler instead of using input bind:value={} and using input value={} on:change(handler).
What I'm curious about is
declared as let data={"name":"jack", "age":31}
If you do $:man=data;, it is a shallow copy, but the value of data does not change even if the value of man changes.
However, only in the case of export let data, when the value of man changes, the value of data also changes at the same time.

I'm curious about the reason and the difference.

I just did $:man= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
I changed it to and ran it, and like Object.assign, the input value of input cannot be changed.
I was wrong about Object.assign until now.
Thank you for your teaching.

These days it's more common to use structuredClone() to create a deep copy.

Thank you for your answer.
I already tried that and it shows the same results.

The reactive statement($:...) keeps overwriting variable man whenever man.name is updated fby bind:value...
//[code-01]
export let data = {name:"jack", age:31};
$: man = Object.assign({},data);


Both man and data are exposed to be monitored

When typing input field, man.name is updated, which triggers variable man to be reset by the reactive statement($:...).
To avoid it, variable man should be removed from the reactive statement([code-01]).
<script>
export let data = {name:"jack", age:31};
// (1)
let man 
// (2)
const clone = (src) => man = structuredClone(src)
// (3)
$: clone(data)
</script>

<input type='text' bind:value={man.name} >
<h1>data value: {data.name}</h1>
<h1>man value: {man.name}</h1>


declare variable man
declare function to clone the data
variable data is exposed to be monitored

man.name is preserved whenever bind:value... changes the text.
code
ReactiveInput.svelte
<script>
export let data = {name:"jack", age:31};
let man
const clone = (src) => man = structuredClone(src)
    
$: clone(data)
</script>
<input type='text' bind:value={man.name} >
<h1>data value: {data.name}</h1>
<h1>man value: {man.name}</h1>

App.svelte
<script>
import ReactiveInput from "./ReactiveInput.svelte"  
const jack = {name: 'jack', age: 31};
const tom = {name: 'Tom', age: 24};
const mark = {name: 'Mark', age: 43};
const persons = [jack, tom, mark]
let idx = 0;
    
const changePerson = () => {
    idx = (idx + 1) % persons.length 
}
</script>

<ReactiveInput data={persons[idx]}></ReactiveInput>
<button on:click={changePerson}>change</button>


I really appreciate your answer.
your solution is
When processing export let data, it works as I want.
We also learned another way to control the responsiveness of variables after $:
However, I still
export let data;
$:man=data;
vs
let data;
$:man=data;
I didn't understand the difference in reactivity.
